# Android SQLcipher PRAGMA problems

Tags: android, pragma, sqlcipher

Hey guys I am having a some problems with SQLcipher db for android 
The documentation is not too descriptive so I could not figure it out.

I am trying to modify the default number of iterations on sqlcipher for android, 
I am editing the notecipher app provided as demo app with sqlcipher, and want to increase the kdf_iter to i.e. 5000

By overriding the getWritableDatabase() method in the database helper i enter the pragma value just after the file is open with the password.

I can open and initialize the database, but I cannot re-open the db if I do a database.close() call.

whenever I close the database on the next open() call I get a :

```
I/Database(807): sqlite returned: error code = 26, msg = file is encrypted or is not a database
E/Database(807): CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
E/Database(807): Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
E/Database(807): info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stephen answer is only partially correct, because according to the [documentation](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#kdf_iter):

> PRAGMA kdf_iter must be called **after** PRAGMA key and before the first actual database operation or it will have no effect.

So the line:

> database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA kdf_iter = 5000");

Must be inserted in the postKey() method, and NOT in preKey().

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a SQLiteDatabaseHook object to call the kdf_iter pragma. This will ensure that the pragma is called immediately after the database is opened, but before it is used.

```
SQLiteDatabaseHook hook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook(){
  public void preKey(SQLiteDatabase database){
    database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA kdf_iter = 5000");
  }
  public void postKey(SQLiteDatabase database){}
}

SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databasePath, password, null, hook);
```