# Unable to open encrypted database using SQLCipher

Tags: android, sql, encryption, sqlcipher

I was using `SQLiteManager` to create an `encrypted database` and storing it in `assets` folder. Then, I move this `database` from `assets` to `data/data/package_name/databases` folder and try to open it at runtime.
The copied file was successfully opened in `SQLiteManager` with origin password, which means I have a correct code for copying (Using DDMS to export the file, then open it in `SQLiteManager`).
However, in the program, I use

```
dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DataProvider.DATABASE_NAME);

SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, context.getString(R.string.KEY_DATABASE), null);
```

to open the file, but the application crashed and have this error:

```
file is encrypted or is not a database: create locale table failed
```

at the line `openOrCreateDatabase`. How can I fix this mess?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20490902/5202007

Comment: Just get rid of the encrypted database. Having a hardcoded passphrase makes the encryption worthless, as anyone can get the passphrase to decrypt it.

Comment: Can you open the database created with SQLiteManager with the SQLCipher command line shell successfully?

Comment: @CommonsWare So how can I protect my database? Can you give me some recommendation? Thanks

Comment: @NickParker It was ok for SQLiteManager even command line shell\

Comment: With regard to the comment from @commonsware and your question about how to protect your database please read https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/database-key-material-and-selection/25

Comment: "So how can I protect my database?" -- get rid of it, and use a Web service. Databases by default are on internal storage, which can only be accessed by developers or rooted device users. That's a small percentage of your audience. Either do not worry about those users (and use an unencrypted database), or do not put the data in persistent storage on the user's device (e.g., use a Web service). Encrypted databases are for defending the user against attackers, not for defending developers against users.